# Lightning Component not working for Non Admin Profile User

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Created an application that exists in our production environment: https://testingxyz.lightning.force.com/c/TeamtoAssignApp.app This application is for the User XYZ as he manages other salespeople in our business.

I wanted to give him (a non-Admin) the ability to update the Team field on user records with profiles of 'xyzResponder (force.com)'.

The javascript and apex server controller I have written do not contain the phrase "with sharing" so I believed that the list update in my controller should be performed agnostic to a running user's profile or permissions.

Unfortunately I get a invalid cross reference when I have XYZ  attempt to change a team for another user.

Comment: You are going to have to post some code as we cannot access the page or the code behind.